# Node.js / winston - Can I append log?

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I use [winston.log](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston?PHPSESSID=02b65463441ebb6580ba41bde8f03247#streaming-logs) to append log files. Every time I restart my application, the exist log is deleted, and new one is created.

Is there any way to append the logs files? so it will deleted just in rotate rule?

Here is the relevant code:

```
    var winston = require('winston');
    var loggerNoCache = new(winston.Logger)({
        transports: [
            new(winston.transports.File)({
                filename: '/var/log/logNo.log',
                options: {
                    highWaterMark: 32
                }
            })
        ]
    });
```

Comment: My understanding is that this is the default... https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/d4fdbadc2f4ab8408261497a116ef80e0f9475a0/lib/winston/transports/file.js#L50

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pass an appendable WriteableStream via the `stream` property, perhaps something like:

```
new(winston.transports.File)({
  stream: fs.createWriteStream('/var/log/logNo.log', {flags: 'a'}),
  options: {
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Most recent solution for streams in winston :

```js
new winston.transports.Stream({
  stream: fs.createWriteStream('/var/log/logNo.log', {flags: 'a'}),
  level: fileLoggingLevel
}));
```